Поддержка цветных эмодзи в Tkinter
я попытался добавить эмодзи в Label в Tkinter и получил черно-белый текст
Подскажите как добавить поддержку цветных эмодзи? (именно изменить способ отображения текста на цветной, не добавить это в виде картинки и т.д)


путём експериментов понял что ткинтер не поддерживает цветные шрифты/эмодзи, и переводит их в черно белые
пример шрифта

код для теста шрифта , и сам шрифт - https://www.fontspace.com/get/family/n9qqw
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="A cat under bed",font=("LOUNGE ITALIC PERSONAL USE",40))
label.pack()
root.mainloop()



путём експериментов понял что ткинтер не поддерживает цветные шрифты/эмодзи, и переводит их в черно белые

У Label есть метод fg, который меняет цвет текста, по дефолту он ставит черный.
label = Label(root, text="A cat under bed",font=("LOUNGE ITALIC PERSONAL USE",40), fg="aqua")
Собственно, fg ставит любой цвет и также принимает hex.

fg не решит проблему, шрифты/эмодзи все так же будут без нормальных текстур
